# how to remove unwanted html tags from tinymce 4.0.6

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4

i am using tinymce 4.0.6,when i copy data from word document all the styles,classes and unwanted html tags are generatin in tinymce.for eg:

```
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify;text-justify:inter-ideograph;
    mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none"><b><span style="color:#1F497D;
    mso-bidi-font-style:italic">About Us </span></b></p>
```

i wanted to clean all unnecessary tags,classes and styles...i want to clean it to below output

```
    <p>
   <strong>About Us </strong>
  </p>
```

in short i want to clean html tags,so that only few html tags work,i only need to keep

```
    <h>,<p>,<br>,<li>,<ul>...etc
```

such important tags only
how can i do it in tinymce 4.0.6

plz help me
thanks in advance

Comment: I guess that should be it, but cannot test: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:valid_elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the best solution ,there is a plugin:paste in tinymce,it is also helpful to remove unwanted things when we copy data from document to tinymce,it maybe helpful for somebody

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `valid_elements` property

For example

```
`valid_elements: "@[id|class|style|title"],h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr[size|noshade]`
```

Will allow `id|class|style|title` attributes on all tags and the allowed tags will be only `h1-6` and `hr`